# Luabridge weak reference to LuaRef data

Tags: c++, data-binding, lua, luabridge

Consider the following example:

```
function Process()
    local Container=NewContainer()
    Container:On(EventType.Add,function()
        Container:DoSomething()
    end)
    -- Does not Garbage Collect
end
```

In luabridge, I store the `function()` as `LuaRef` which extends the lifetime for the `Container` and it will not be GCed because it's a `RefCountedObjectPtr`

Here is a workaround that I use to use a weak table which works, but it looks ugly:

```
function Process()
    local Container=NewContainer()
    local ParamsTable={ Container=Container }
    setmetatable(ParamsTable, { __mode = 'k' })

    Container:On(EventType.Add,function()
        ParamsTable.Container:DoSomething()
    end)
    -- Garbage Collects fine
end
```

Is there any way to have a `LuaRef` that functions similar to this? Or maybe there is another workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the way I approached this problem:

1. Create a wrapper class around C++ luabridge class (If you have `class Display.A()` in C++, create class `A()` in Lua)
2. Store a weak table inside that wrapper class (`self.WeakTable={}` and `setmetatable(self.WeakTable, { __mode = 'k' })`)
3. In the weak table, reference self: (`self.WeakTable.self=self`)
4. Pass `self.WeakTable` to C++ and store in as `LuaRef` - this will gc
5. Create a wrapper function like so:

   ```
   Container:On(EventType.Add,function(WeakTableParams) 
      WeakTableParams.self.Callback();
   end)
   ```

Comment: if you accept your own answer, you will get less people to look at your question. You can still accept it afterwards.